# How to stop a loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to stop a foreach loop in PHP, like this,

```
$arr = array('Joe', 'Jude', 'James', 'Pitch', 'Tim');
$i=0;
foreach($arr as $val){
    echo $val;
    if($i == 2){
         //Stop looping
    }
}
```

Is there anyway how to do that, if yes how do I that?

Thank you.

Comment: [The `break` keyword.](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Comment: btw, you cannot `break` from your loop since you're not incrementing `$i`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`break`](http://php.net/control-structures.break) and increment `$i`.

```
$arr = array('Joe', 'Jude', 'James', 'Pitch', 'Tim');
$i=0;
foreach($arr as $val){
    echo $val;
    if(++$i == 2){
       break; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use good old keyword `break` here as well. Followed by a semicolon `;` of course.

```
if($i == 2){
     break;
}
```

[Manual for `break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can break out of a loop with [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php).

Answer (score 0):

1)As said earlier u need to increment the loop.
2)...if ur using multiple "foreach" that are nested,you can do break 'n' to get out of n nested loop,where n will specify any number from 1 to the total number of loops that you have used.Hope it helps!